# Java integer convert to only 2 byte array missing extra 00

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I have a stream of data which I have first read using this method.

```
int messageSerialNumber = r.readUnsignedShort();
```

Next, I convert it into

```
byte[] byteMessageSerialNumber = new byte[2];
byteMessageSerialNumber[0] = (byte) messageSerialNumber;
byteMessageSerialNumber[1] = (byte) (messageSerialNumber >>> 8);
```

Next I build a bigger buffer array and add other data into it.

```
ByteBuffer bufReply = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);
bufReply.put(replyMessageID);
bufReply.put(byteMessageSerialNumber);
byte[] fullMessageReply=bufReply.array();
```

What I want is the `byteMessageSerialNumber` to have 2 bytes so what happens now is that it's without the extra `00`.

So it becomes

```
05 01 00 27 36 81 82 01 2C
```

It's supposed to be

```
05 01 00 27 36 81 82 01 00 2C
```

Comment: What value of `int messageSerialNumber` should generate `05 01 00 27 36 81 82 01 00 2C`? (so it is easier for us to test)

Comment: The integer value of messageSerialNumber is 44 and hex is 2C

Comment: So you want `byteMessageSerialNumber` in final array to take only one byte if it fits there?

Comment: No I want it to be two byte e.g. 2C to be 00 2c when I send into bufReply.put(byteMessageSerialNumber);

Comment: Please include the actual code used to produce this serialization and the output.

Comment: `ByteBuffer` has a method to adding integer values, try to use it:
`bufReply.putInt(byteMessageSerialNumber);`

Comment: @TEXHIK I have tried but it gives me 4 bytes I just need 2 bytes

Comment: @user8012596 If it works, and all is OK, you just get 2 more bytes - cast int to short. And yes, as Stefan says, you get wrong order of most and less significant part of original int value in your convertion.

Comment: @TEXHIK I tried this now bufReply.putShort((short)messageSerialNumber);. So this does not require me to convert into byte array first any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple. Swap like this:

```
byteMessageSerialNumber[0] = (byte) (messageSerialNumber >>> 8);    
byteMessageSerialNumber[1] = (byte) messageSerialNumber;
```

The first byte should be the first, **most significant** part of `messageSerialNumber`, the second byte should be the last, **least significant** part of `messageSerialNumber`.

Comment: I dont get you mean by the left part and right part. Can you describe ?

Comment: I notice for example if my hex value is 59 the byte becomes 00 89 it turns to be integer instead ?

Comment: When you do >>> 8 you shift 8 positions. Those positions are all =0 for 59. Try with a higher number, eg 47702 (**10111010**01010110). Then you get 186, or 186-256=-70 as byte (10111010, or 186-256=-70 as byte). Not a very good explanation but there are good tutorials out there. Anyways, it should be clear that the >>>8 should be done in the first byte (byte[0]).

Comment: not so clear meaning you do shift or extraction for the bytes ?

Comment: When you do cast an integer to a byte the value will be truncated. So the byte will be built using only the 8 rightmost binary positions. So for 47702 / 1011101001010110, byteMessageSerialNumber[1] gets its value from 01010110. When you do >>> 8 you shift positions. The effect will be that 1011101001010110 becomes 10111010. So byteMessageSerialNumber[0] gets its value from 10111010.

Comment: But if we do this truncation wont it loose its value. So when you do a shift it do change the position then in this case what will be value of byteMessageSerialNumber[1]

Comment: Yes, you lose part of the value by truncating. Integer 47702 becomes byte 86. But you compensate that by shifting and converting to another byte. Essentially what you do is that you convert your integer to two bytes with values 186 and 86. No data is lost (as long there are max 16 posistions in the binary value). You get back to 47702 using 186*256+86, where 256 is the same as 1<<8.